# EmberJS production website don't have hash on urls

Tags: url, ember.js, hash

I'm learning some MV* frameworks, and looks at emberjs. I'm learning the framework and it seems really nice. I just look at some of emberJS example websites and I noticed that the transition of their pages don't have the hash(#) on urls? Why is that? On my localhost, I got ('#')/page on url. Can you explain to me why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

Keep in mind that all the URLs used by your app need to serve your Ember `index.html`, or reloading those pages will not work.

More info: [Guides - Specifying the URL Type](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/)

Comment: Is that it? hmmmm, then and I don't have the hash?, I see, I looked at the link you provided. And read `This is useful for testing, or when you need to manage state with your Router, but temporarily don't want it to muck with the URL (for example when you embed your application in a larger page).`. Testing? hmm, can you explain about this please?

Comment: The comment is referring to `location: 'none'`, which completely disables any form of URL changing in the router.

`location: 'history'` however will use `history.pushState` and the like to change the URL of the window while navigating around, without using hashes.